# Envio UTF-8 por POST não funciona

Tags: android, post, utf-8, asynctask

Tenha a seguinte classe de conexão:

```
public class Conexao {

public static String postDados(String urlUsuario, String parametrosUsuario) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {

        url = new URL(urlUsuario);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Lenght", "" + Integer.toString(parametrosUsuario.getBytes().length));

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "pt-BR");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parametrosUsuario);
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String linha;
        StringBuffer resposta = new StringBuffer();

        while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         resposta.append(linha);
            resposta.append('\r');
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        return resposta.toString();

    } catch (Exception erro) {

        return  null;
    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Porem quando tento enviar algo por utf-8 assim, por exemplo, ele não fica em utf-8:

```
url = "url";
parametros = 

new cadastro.registro().execute(url);
```

Pra ir, eu tenho que mandar pelo get, na url:

```
url = "url" + "?texto=" + "~~a@#";
parametros = "";

new cadastro.registro().execute(url);
```

Mas eu preciso que seja por POST e não por GET, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
private class registro extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected  String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {
    }
    }
```

Comment: Tente passar o charset no `Content-Type`: `connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");`

Comment: @Henrique vou testar aqui agora e já t retorno

Comment: @Henrique cara, parece que agora os paramentros não estão indo

Comment: @Henrique pera, foi sim, eu q digitei um negócio errado aqui kkkk, mas não em utf-8, no mysql o registro onde tinha caractere especial ficou com ?, tipo: j?ao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver:

Eu troquei isso:

```
 DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new 
 DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parametrosUsuario);
    dataOutputStream.flush();
    dataOutputStream.close()
```

Por isso:

```
OutputStreamWriter outPutStream = new 
OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "utf-8");
        outPutStream.write(parametrosUsuario);
        outPutStream.flush();
        outPutStream.close();
```

Agora funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Como você não está passando o tipo de `Character Set`, será a API que irá definir qual o charset a ser utilizado, geralmente é `ISO-8859-1`, pode verificar com mais detalhes na [`RFC 8187`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8187).

Para especificar o uso de uma charset específico, é necessário passar essa informação para o protocolo HTTP, utilizando o cabeçalho `Content-Type` da seguinte forma:

```
Content-Type: media-type;charset=charset-type
```

onde:

- `media-type` corresponde ao formato de dados a ser transmitido ([`RFC 7231`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1))
- `charset` indica o esquema da codificação de caracteres ([`RFC 7231`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.2))

Para seu caso, seria necessario alterar a linha:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

para:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Como eu tinha dito antes, não funcionou, a unica maneira foi colocar o 
 utf8_encode($_POST['nome']); no php

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi corretamente, está em enviar os dados pelo POST certo? Tente substituir o parametro da InputStream pelo seguinte parametro:

```
InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
```

Se precisar enviar uma informação para URL em php que receba um parâmetro pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("parametro1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(valor1, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("parametro2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(valor2, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nessa é já já t retorno

Comment: Caso precise, posso ajudar montar toda requisição, pois em sua pergunta, você utiliza de alguns métodos que eu não uso.

Comment: cada, eu fiz aqui, porém não funcionou, os caracteres continuam estranhos

Comment: Ah, e perdão pela dmr, tava almoçando aqui kkkk

Comment: Voce está usando esta URL ? url = "url" + "?texto=" + "~~a@#";

Comment: essa "url" no caso seria minha url q eu dx assim pra n mostrar, mas o envio ocorre, coloquei um echo no php pra ver oq retorno, e este não fica em utf-8, mas eu consegui resolver aqui, vou postar a resposta abaixo